# Search for same substrings in a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list (around 18000 items) of strings, well I need to find same substring in this list. Bellow is an example:
List example:
"test1"
"test 2"
"est 2"
"west1"

well I need this result:

"test" - 2

"est" - 4

"est1" - 2

"est 2" - 2

well I need it using linq to make searching fast (if possible).
Thanks in advance

Comment: LINQ won't necessarily make the operation fast. LINQ is compiled into the appropriate for loops anyway...

Comment: You'll find people more willing to help if you show [what you've tried so far](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I think any solution for *all* strings (like in your example) is likely to be O(N^2) so it's not going to be hugely fast. Checking each individual string will be O(N). Just to confirm: If we add to your sample list of strings the string "e", would the count for that be 5? (Because it's in "e", "test", "est", "est1" and "est 2")

Comment: You have a list of a lot of strings and want to detect (and count) common substrings? Good luck with that... basically you need to go through each and every string, build all possible substrings (<- hard part), probably use them as keys in a `Dictionary<string, int>` and count the occurence of each key. This *will* get slow.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, generally you are right, if we add e in list I will need result e - 5. In real case I will ignore substrings with lenght < 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *guess* that this is what you want:

```
var listWithSubstring = originalList.Where(i => i.Contains("est"));
```

Comment: maybe .Count would be enough but this will cover it also

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure what @SergiuCojocaru wants, but this should be enough. Though you may be right, that I could mention `.Count`/`.Count()` in my answer.

Comment: well string may or may not contain est. I need to find all similar substrings. For example if in above list I will add "home" and "omen", algorithm will need to show previous results +  ome -2. So in fact I do not know the initial list on coding stage.

Comment: @SergiuCojocaru then you want to find common substrings, which is too *big* (at least without some code from you) to answer in this question. However I can direct you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418504/algorithm-to-find-common-substring-across-n-strings)