# Longest common substring from more than two strings - C++

Tags: c++, string, sequence, matching, longest-substring

I need to compute the longest common substrings from a set of filenames in C++.

Precisely, I have an std::list of std::strings (or the QT equivalent, also fine)

```
char const *x[] = {"FirstFileWord.xls", "SecondFileBlue.xls", "ThirdFileWhite.xls", "ForthFileGreen.xls"};
std::list<std::string> files(x, x + sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x));
```

I need to compute the n distinct longest common substrings of all strings, in this case e.g. for n=2

```
 "File" and ".xls"
```

If I could compute the longest common subsequence, I could cut it out it and run the algorithm again to get the second longest, so essentially this boils down to:

Is there a (reference?) implementation for computing the LCS of a std::list of std::strings?

---

This is not a good answer but a dirty solution that I have - brute force on a QList of QUrls from which only the part after the last "/" is taken. I'd love to replace this with "proper" code.

(I have discovered http://www.icir.org/christian/libstree/ - which  would help greatly, but I can't get it to compile on my machine. Someone used this maybe?)

```
QString SubstringMatching::getMatchPattern(QList<QUrl> urls)
    {
    QString a;

    int foundPosition = -1;
    int foundLength = -1;
    for (int i=urls.first().toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1; i<urls.first().toString().length(); i++)
    {
        bool hit=true;
        int xj;
        for (int j=0; j<urls.first().toString().length()-i+1; j++ ) // try to match from position i up to the end of the string :: test character at pos. (i+j)
        {
            if (!hit) break;

            QString firstString = urls.first().toString().right( urls.first().toString().length()-i ).left( j ); // this needs to match all k strings
            //qDebug() << "SEARCH " << firstString;

            for (int k=1; k<urls.length(); k++) // test all other strings, k = test string number
            {
                if (!hit) break;

                //qDebug() << " IN  " << urls.at(k).toString().right(urls.at(k).toString().length() - urls.at(k).toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                //qDebug() << " RES " << urls.at(k).toString().indexOf(firstString, urls.at(k).toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                if (urls.at(k).toString().indexOf(firstString, urls.at(k).toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1)<0) {
                    xj = j;
                    //qDebug() << "HIT LENGTH " << xj-1 << " : " << firstString;
                    hit = false;
                }
            }

        }
        if (hit) xj = urls.first().toString().length()-i+1; // hit up to the end of the string
        if ((xj-2)>foundLength) // have longer match than existing, j=1 is match length
        {
            foundPosition = i; // at the current position
            foundLength = xj-1;
            //qDebug() << "Found at " << i << " length " << foundLength;
        }
    }

    a = urls.first().toString().right( urls.first().toString().length()-foundPosition ).left( foundLength );
    //qDebug() << a;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: This maybe useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418504/algorithm-to-find-common-substring-across-n-strings

Comment: I have clicked through hundreds of similar question without finding an answer, including the one above and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248728/how-to-find-longest-common-substring-using-c. The closest I got was http://homepage.virgin.net/cdm.henderson/site/cpp/lcs/index.htm but that is for subsequence, not substring.

Comment: This is a nontrivial problem. An exhaustive search is necessary. (If my first glance holds)

Comment: There should be an good solution using suffix trees, at least if I understand the library usage example of libstree right - http://www.icir.org/christian/libstree/manual/c39.html. Unfortunately, it doesn't compile and is way too complex for my needs.

Comment: You should keep all the matching substrings in a `vector`. For each strings, each character should be compared to others. Smallest-length string may be a reference for starting point and helper functions like `int Find(const char* str, char ch)` and `void Sort(char* words[])` would be very useful.

Comment: What I would do is enter all those strings into a `vector`.  Then I would have a `string` sub.  I would calculate the largest substring between the first and second strings and put it in sub.  Then I would see if sub was a substring of the rest of the strings you are testing, and if not, check for a substring in sub and the string...

Comment: Check this link [**Analysis of Longest common substring matching**](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/10/analysis-of-longest-common-substring_18.html)

Answer (score 1):

If as you say suffix trees are too heavyweight or otherwise impractical, the following
fairly simple brute-force approach may be adequate for your application.

I assume distinct substrings shall be non-overlapping and are picked from
left to right.

Even with these assumptions, there need not be a unique set that comprises 
"the *N* distinct longest common substrings" of a set of strings. Whatever *N* is, 
there might be more than *N* distinct common substrings all of the same maximal 
length and any choice of *N* from among them would be arbitrary. Accordingly 
the solution finds the at-most *N* *sets* of the longest distinct common 
substrings in which all those of the same length are one set.

The algorithm is as follows:

- *Q* is the target quota of lengths.
- *Strings* is the problem set of strings.
- *Results* is an initially empty multimap that maps a length to a set of strings,
  *Results[l]* being the set with length *l*
- *N*, initially 0, is the number of distinct lengths represented in *Results*
- If *Q* is 0 or *Strings* is empty return *Results*
- Find any shortest member of *Strings*; keep a copy of it *S* and remove it 
  from *Strings*. We proceed by comparing the substrings of *S* with those
  of *Strings* because all the common substrings of {*Strings*, *S*} must be
  substrings of *S*.
- Iteratively generate all the substrings of *S*, longest first, using the 
  obvious nested loop controlled by offset and length. For each substring *ss* of 
  *S*:

  - If *ss* is not a common substring of *Strings*, next.
  - Iterate over *Results[l]* for *l* >= the length of *ss* until end of 
    *Results* or until *ss* is found to be a substring of the examined
    result. In the latter case, *ss* is not distinct from a result already
    in hand, so next.
  - *ss* is common substring distinct from any already in hand. Iterate over 
    *Results[l]* for *l* < the length of *ss*, deleting each result that is a 
    substring of *ss*, because all those are shorter than *ss* and not distinct 
    from it. *ss* is now a common substring distinct from any already in hand and 
    all others that remain in hand are distinct from *ss*.
  - For *l* = the length of *ss*, check whether *Results[l]* exists, i.e. if 
    there are any results in hand the same length as *ss*. If not, call that
    a *NewLength* condition.
  - Check also if *N* == *Q*, i.e. we have already reached the target quota of distinct
    lengths. If *NewLength* obtains and also *N* == *Q*, call that a *StickOrRaise* condition.
  - If *StickOrRaise* obtains then compare the length of *ss* with *l* = the
    length of the shortest results in hand. If *ss* is shorter than *l*
    then it is too short for our quota, so next. If *ss* is longer than *l*
    then all the shortest results in hand are to be ousted in favour of *ss*, so delete
    *Results[l]* and decrement *N*.
  - Insert *ss* into *Results* keyed by its length.
  - If *NewLength* obtains, increment *N*.
  - Abandon the inner iteration over substrings of *S* that have the
    same offset of *ss* but are shorter, because none of them are distinct
    from *ss*.
  - Advance the offset in *S* for the outer iteration by the length of *ss*,
    to the start of the next non-overlapping substring.
- Return *Results*.

Here is a program that implements the solution and demonstrates it with
a list of strings:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Get a non-const iterator to the shortest string in a list
list<string>::iterator shortest_of(list<string> & strings)
{
    auto where = strings.end();
    size_t min_len = size_t(-1);
    for (auto i = strings.begin(); i != strings.end(); ++i) {
        if (i->size() < min_len) {
            where = i;
            min_len = i->size();
        }
    }
    return where;
}

// Say whether a string is a common substring of a list of strings
bool 
is_common_substring_of(
    string const & candidate, list<string> const & strings)
{
    for (string const & s : strings) {
        if (s.find(candidate) == string::npos) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


/* Get a multimap whose keys are the at-most `quota` greatest 
    lengths of common substrings of the list of strings `strings`, each key 
    multi-mapped to the set of common substrings of that length.
*/
multimap<size_t,string> 
n_longest_common_substring_sets(list<string> & strings, unsigned quota)
{
    size_t nlengths = 0;
    multimap<size_t,string> results;
    if (quota == 0) {
        return results;
    }
    auto shortest_i = shortest_of(strings);
    if (shortest_i == strings.end()) {
        return results;
    }
    string shortest = *shortest_i;
    strings.erase(shortest_i);
    for ( size_t start = 0; start < shortest.size();) {
        size_t skip = 1;
        for (size_t len = shortest.size(); len > 0; --len) {
            string subs = shortest.substr(start,len);
            if (!is_common_substring_of(subs,strings)) {
                continue;
            }
            auto i = results.lower_bound(subs.size());
            for (   ;i != results.end() && 
                    i->second.find(subs) == string::npos; ++i) {}
            if (i != results.end()) {
                continue;
            }
            for (i = results.begin(); 
                    i != results.end() && i->first < subs.size(); ) {
                if (subs.find(i->second) != string::npos) {
                    i = results.erase(i);
                } else {
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            auto hint = results.lower_bound(subs.size());
            bool new_len = hint == results.end() || hint->first != subs.size();
            if (new_len && nlengths == quota) {
                size_t min_len = results.begin()->first;
                if (min_len > subs.size()) {
                    continue;
                }
                results.erase(min_len);
                --nlengths;
            }
            nlengths += new_len;
            results.emplace_hint(hint,subs.size(),subs);
            len = 1;
            skip = subs.size();
        }
        start += skip;
    }
    return results; 
}

// Testing ...

int main()
{
    list<string> strings{
        "OfBitWordFirstFileWordZ.xls", 
        "SecondZWordBitWordOfFileBlue.xls", 
        "ThirdFileZBitWordWhiteOfWord.xls", 
        "WordFourthWordFileBitGreenZOf.xls"};

    auto results = n_longest_common_substring_sets(strings,4);
    for (auto const & val : results) {
        cout << "length: " << val.first 
        << ", substring: " << val.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
length: 1, substring: Z
length: 2, substring: Of
length: 3, substring: Bit
length: 4, substring: .xls
length: 4, substring: File
length: 4, substring: Word
```

(Built with gcc 4.8.1)