# Longest repeated substring

Tags: python, string, loops, longest-substring

learning python as I go for school work. Essentially, I need to find the longest repeated substring in a list of string as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418504/algorithm-to-find-common-substring-across-n-strings?rq=1). I have been reading through [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) and have an understanding of what I should do.

so far my implementation is as follows:

```
def long_rptr_subString(testList):
    longSubstring = ''

    if len(testList) > 1 and len(testList[0]) > 0:
        for i in range(len(testList[0])):
            for j in range(len(testList[0])-i+1):
                if j > len(longSubstring) and all(testList[0][i:i+j] in x for x in testList):
                    longSubstring = testList[0][i:i+j]
    return longSubstring
```

now when I call my function with let's say `['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr']`
I get the correct result of `'id'` as being my longest substring.

However, when I pass the list `['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr', 'balh', 'tejka', 'djakljskdl', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah']` I don't get any return results. I *should* be getting back `'blah'` as my longest substring, but I haven't figured out a way to accomplish this. It seems I am only able to match substrings when they are in ALL items of the list. How might I modify my code/logic to get the longest substring that occurs more than once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only match substrings in `all` items because that's exactly what you ask for:

```
all(testList[0][i:i+j] in x for x in testList)
```

Even if you change that, you can only find the longest substring that is in the *first* substring, because you only check through `testlist[0]` .

Instead, try something like:

```
def longest_substr(lst):
    longest = None
    for word in lst:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(word)+1):
                if ((longest is None or (j - i > len(longest))) and
                    sum(word[i:j] in w for w in lst) > 1):
                    longest = word[i:j]
    return longest
```

This finds the longest substring that's in at least two (`> 1`) of the words (or will `return None` for an empty list or list of empty strings) and gives me the following results:

```
>>> longest_substr(['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr'])
'lid'
>>> longest_substr(['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr', 'balh', 'tejka', 'djakljskdl', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'])
'blah'
```

Note that, once you remove the requirement that the substring must be in all strings, the longest in your first list of words is actually `'lid'`.

Comment: Can you modify this to give back the longest sequence of whole words that might not be present in all of the input strings? I posted a question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149929/find-longest-sequence-of-common-words-from-list-of-words-in-python

Answer (score 2):

If you really want `blah`, then you need to remove the condition that your longest common subsequence must be in all strings. Thus, you could do this (note, you get `lid` for the first example):

```
def allCommonSubstrings(s1, s2):
    answer = set()
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s1)+1):
            if s1[i:j] in s2:
                answer.add(s1[i:j])
    return answer

def longestCommonSubstring(strings):
    common = set()
    for s1,s2 in itertools.combinations(strings, 2):
        common = common.union(allCommonSubstrings(s1, s2))
    return max(common, key=len)

In [288]: longestCommonSubstring(['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr', 'balh', 'tejka', 'djakljskdl', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'])
Out[288]: 'blah'

In [289]: longestCommonSubstring(['slide', 'glidb', 'flidt', 'cridz', 'bidr'])
Out[289]: 'lid'
```