# How to compare a set of strings to find common substrings

Tags: string, grep, substring, text-comparison

I'm trying to create a script that looks through a list of strings files and reports on the sub-strings that are most common between them.

For example:

1. Hello, I am string one. I like apples and oranges. We are all strings here.
2. Hello, I am string two. I like apples and oranges. We are all strings  here.
3. Hello, I am string three. I like apples and oranges. We are all strings  here.
4. Hello, I am string four. I like apples and oranges. I like to express my individuality.

I'd like the script to tell me what are the common elements between the strings, above a certain threshold (for example, 5 characters).

Ideally I'd be told

- "I like apples and oranges" occurs in all files
- "Hello, I am string" occurs in all files
- "We are all strings here" occurs in three of the files.

If functions exist to do this in technologies I'm familiar with - SQL, Javascript, PHP, Ruby or Bash -I'll be extremely happy...

Many thanks,

Jack

Comment: This question is closely related, and has many relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410822/how-can-i-detect-common-substrings-in-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard problem known as the [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Here is a Python implementation of the algorithm using dynamic programming: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Common_Subsequence

I don't think that any standard library (C, Java, PHP, Python, Javascript, Ruby, etc.) comes with such a function. But you may look for implementations here: http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%22longest+common+subsequence%22

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Now I know the name I managed to find some pre-built implementations: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP